# WP REST api.wordpress.org discovery

Tags: rest-api

I have no problem doing REST discovery of routes and endpoints on **wordpress.org**:

```
https://wordpress.org/?rest_route
```

I'm trying to do the same for **api.wordpress.org** with no success. The following:

```
https://api.wordpress.org/?rest_route
```

redirects me to `https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/`, which is **REST API Handbook**.

Does anyone know, how to do REST discovery on **api.wordpress.org**? Maybe it's not available.

Comment: you can found a list of endpoints here : https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API

Comment: Thanks. I know this document, but it is almost useless, especially Plugins section. Arguments are not documented. There is a new `/plugins/info/1.2/` in alpha, already. I'm testing it, and it works, but it is missing some info, available in `/plugins/info/1.1/`. I need to know, if there are some arguments, I can use, to fill that gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://api.wordpress.org is a custom PHP API and is not running WordPress. Thus, there's no WP REST API that you could use for discovery. That URL has nothing to do with the REST API in core except for that redirect to the handbook.

Unfortunately not all of the API endpoints are documented or either open sourced, as you can see when [browsing SVN](http://meta.svn.wordpress.org/sites/trunk/api.wordpress.org/public_html/) or looking at the [plugins API code](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/browser/sites/trunk/wordpress.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin-directory/standalone/class-plugins-info-api.php) directly.

If you have any questions about stuff that's currently in development there, you should really ask in the [#meta Slack channel](https://make.wordpress.org/chat/) instead of here or raise an issue on [Meta Trac](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/).

Also, since it's really in development and not intended for public use just yet, I'd highly recommend you to simply stick to the 1.0 or 1.1 version of the API.

Comment: Thanks for the links. They are as useful as a good documentation.